# How to create a Cordova and TypeScript project by cmd

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript

I use Cordova to develop a mobile application,
and I type `cordova create MyApp` in command-line to create a Cordova project.

I can use JavaScript but I need use the TypeScript in my project.

Please help me to create a Cordova project, powered by TypeScript without Visual Studio, or help me to add TypeScript to my Cordova project.

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you try to provide what have you done so far?

Comment: yes, i install nodejs and npm,then type npm install -g cordova in cmd then type cordova create MyApp

Comment: this create for me the cordova application, i can use to it javascript but i need use to typescript...

Comment: Try running npm install typescript --save inside your project folder

Answer (score 3):

**In essence** (without getting into code and asset bundling) what you'll want to do is to

- ***write your "TypeScript" code in another file, for example `index.ts` and then compile with output to `...\MyApp\www\js\index.js`***,

where `MyApp` is your Cordova app folder and `index.js` is the one referenced in your app's `index.html` (`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>`).

- ***you need to install the command-line TypeScript compiler***, which can be installed as a Node.js package. Open the "Windows Command Prompt" or "Terminal" and type:

`npm install -g typescript`

To see if TypeScript is installed, type `tsc -v` . This should print a version number, so you'll see something like `Version 2.7.2` .

- next ***copy `index.js` to `index.ts`*** so your `\js\` folder will contain both files
- after you edit and save your TypeScript code in `index.ts`, use "Command Prompt" or "Terminal", change directory to the `\js\` folder, then run `tsc index.ts` (this will compile `index.ts` and update `index.js`)

*Note:* when building your Cordova app, you will not need the source .ts file

This is a manual process (you'll have to do it every time you change your code), but I think it will get you started and it gives you an understanding of what is going on before you move to bundling, etc...

**Next steps to take into account:**

- use an editor with TypeScript support (such as Visual Studio Code)
- use a `dist` folder so you have clear separation of source files
- use `tsconfig.json`
- use Webpack (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/)